# Finding all combinations in javascript

Tags: javascript, combinations

I am creating a game and I need to generate some game pieces. Each piece is an array consisting of 4 numbers(each represents a property of the piece) ranging from 0-2. I need to generate all combinations to get all the game pieces.

So I would need [1, 0, 2, 0], [2, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1, 0] etc..

There should be 81 total combinations of [a, b, c, d] where each variable is a number 0-2.

I am using javascript but any psudocode would be helpful.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Those are not permutations. Permutations are [1,2,3], [1,3,2], [2,1,3], [2,3,1], [3,1,2], [3,2,1].

Comment: AFAIK, what you want is called *combinations*, not permutations.

Comment: Right, not combinations. That's what I have in my example correct?

Comment: Sounds like homework... tip: You can make 4 nested loops.

Comment: If it were homework, they wouldn't be calling combinations permutations.

Answer (score 3):

If it is a homework, tag it as such.

```
var BASE = 3, LEN = 4, LIMIT = Math.round(Math.pow(BASE, LEN));
var c = [];
for (var i = 0; i < LIMIT; ++i) {
  var item = [];
  for (var j = 0, k = i; j < LEN; ++j, k = Math.floor(k/BASE)) {
    item.push(k % BASE);
  }
  c.push(item);
}
```

Here is a more tricky solution but showing the math behind it better, hopefully:

```
var BASE = 3, LEN = 4;
var powers = [];
for (var i = 0, LIMIT = 1; i < LEN; ++i, LIMIT *= BASE) {
  powers.push(LIMIT);
}
var c = [];
for (i = 0; i < LIMIT; ++i) {
  c.push(powers.map(function(basePower) {
    return Math.floor(i/basePower) % BASE;
  }));
}
```

Comment: After seeing @katspaugh made generic solution, I'm gonna make mine generic as well...

Answer (score 3):

Mine

```
var arr=[];
for (var str,i=0;i<81;i++) {
  str = i.toString(3);
  arr.push(("000"+str).slice(-4)); // Hmm, I thought slice returned an array.
}
```

Here is an update taking into account the comments from @katspaugh and @herby

```
var arr=[];
for (var str,i=81;i<162;i++) {
  str = i.toString(3);
  arr.push((str).slice(-4).split('').map(Number));
}
```

Comment: `toString(3)`! I completely forgot!

Comment: @herby, it's fortunate, because this `toString`/`slice` approach is [42% slower](http://jsperf.com/maths-vs-naivitet).

Comment: As for the slice, you can instead use Array's slice explicitly: `[].slice.call("000"+str, 4)`. Also, if `i` would start with 81 and ended with `< 162 /* 2*81 */` then `"000"+str` trick is not needed.

Comment: @katspaugh: Not to mention that it does not solve the problem correctly because it stores one-character strings, not Numbers (`map(Number)` would do the trick, but make it even slower).

Comment: Did you measure how slow it was making 81 arrays? Also I think mine is easier to read than your generic ones

Comment: Interesting [blog post](http://www.wirfs-brock.com/allen/posts/166) and a resulting [warning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Tricky_use_case) - also map is IE9+ btw

Answer (score 1):

```
var BASE = 3, COMB_LEN = 4

var max = parseInt(new Array(COMB_LEN + 1).join(BASE - 1), BASE),
    comb = new Array(COMB_LEN + 1).join(0).split('').map(Number)

var combinations = [], i, n
for (i = 0; i <= max; i++) {
    n = i.toString(BASE).split('').map(Number)
    combinations.push(
        comb.slice(0, COMB_LEN - n.length).concat(n)
    )
}
```

Comment: This, too, produces strings, not numbers, doesn't it?